# Find the average price for every product type in array

Tags: php, arrays, count, average

So I have this array:

```
$arr = array(
    array('category' => 'box', 'product' => 'gloves', 'quantity' => 45, 'price' => 30),
    array('category' => 'karate', 'product' => 'gloves', 'quantity' => 55, 'price' => 25),
    array('category' => 'mma', 'product' => 'gloves', 'quantity' => 55, 'price' => 35),
    array('category' => 'mma', 'product' => 'shorts', 'quantity' => 120, 'price' => 50),
    array('category' => 'karate', 'product' => 'belt', 'quantity' => 25, 'price' => 55),
    array('category' => 'judo', 'product' => 'costume', 'quantity' => 30, 'price' => 90),
    array('category' => 'karate', 'product' => 'belt', 'quantity' => 25, 'price' => 90)
);
```

I need to find out the average price for every product type, for e.g:
(box gloves + karate gloves + mma gloves) / 3 = (30+25+35)/3 = 30.

This is my code right now that output an array with the sum for every product type:

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {

    $tmp[$arr[$key]['product']] = isset($tmp[$arr[$key]['product']]) ? $tmp[$arr[$key]['produs']]: 0;

    $tmp[$arr[$key]['product']] = $tmp[$arr[$key]['product']] + $arr[$key]['price'];     

}
```

The output:

```
[gloves] => 90
[shorts] => 50
[costume] => 90
[belt] => 145
```

**How can I found out the count for every product type?**

For example for gloves it will be 90/3, the "3" number I don't know how to obtain it.

Comment: array_filter and array_reduce are your friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example without [arrray functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php):

```
$arr = array(
    array('category' => 'box', 'product' => 'gloves', 'quantity' => 45, 'price' => 30),
    array('category' => 'karate', 'product' => 'gloves', 'quantity' => 55, 'price' => 25),
    array('category' => 'mma', 'product' => 'gloves', 'quantity' => 55, 'price' => 35),
    array('category' => 'mma', 'product' => 'shorts', 'quantity' => 120, 'price' => 50),
    array('category' => 'karate', 'product' => 'belt', 'quantity' => 25, 'price' => 55),
    array('category' => 'judo', 'product' => 'costume', 'quantity' => 30, 'price' => 90),
    array('category' => 'karate', 'product' => 'belt', 'quantity' => 25, 'price' => 90)
);

$tmp = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (isset($tmp[$value['product']])) {
        $tmp[$value['product']]['total'] += $value['price'];
        $tmp[$value['product']]['price'] += 1;
    } else {
        $tmp[$value['product']]['total'] = $value['price'];
        $tmp[$value['product']]['price'] = 1;
    }
}

foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {
    $tmp[$key] = $value['total'] / $value['price'];
}
```

`$tmp` values:

```
[
    'gloves' => (int) 30,
    'shorts' => (int) 50,
    'belt' => (float) 72.5,
    'costume' => (int) 90
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of summing the prices as you go, just add them to an array.

```
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $products[$item['product']][] = $item['price'];
}
```

Then you can calculate the average of the resulting groups.

```
$products = array_map(function($product){
    return array_sum($product) / count($product);
}, $products);

var_dump($products);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [***array_reduce***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [***array_map***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) functions:

```
$result = array_map(function($v){
    $c = count($v);
    return ($c > 1)? array_sum($v)/$c : $v[0];
}, array_reduce($arr, function($r, $a){
    $r[$a['product']][] = $a['price'];  // accumulating prices for each `product`
    return $r;
}, []));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [gloves] => 30
    [shorts] => 50
    [belt] => 72.5
    [costume] => 90
)
```